# EJS not templating all properties from given object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

So I am trying to template a JSON object to an ejs view. However, only some of the properties from the given object are being templated onto the view. When I run my website on localhost, it works fine, but when I run it on my VPS where the same code is deployed, it doesn't work.

Here's what the object looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d9492bbb5f314b03a07b5"),
    "date" : "Mon Mar 02 2020",
    "author" : "hello",
    "title" : "Fake Blog Post on How to Rig a Rod",
    "content" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacinia viverra ultricies. Duis vel dui ante. Nulla venenatis ornare lorem et ornare. Phasellus vestibulum viverra diam quis pulvinar. Curabitur sit amet ultricies purus. Donec a pretium justo. Mauris pharetra, nisl ac vehicula pulvinar, diam sapien fringilla enim, auctor eleifend lorem justo et turpis. Nam eget tristique velit. Sed gravida sapien sed nisl sodales, eget scelerisque arcu tristique. Phasellus molestie neque in suscipit pulvinar. Nunc nec lectus quis lorem consequat accumsan. Praesent nec odio placerat, bibendum dolor sit amet, rhoncus quam. Donec et lacus eu felis sollicitudin porttitor. Cras nec aliquet neque. Donec erat risus, porttitor ac pharetra sit amet, mattis vel est. Morbi vel malesuada tellus. Proin non congue purus, vitae dapibus lacus. Curabitur lacinia urna vel sapien euismod rutrum. Pellentesque feugiat orci a mi consectetur suscipit. Duis sed eros at dui facilisis dictum. Cras enim turpis, imperdiet vel lacus id, pulvinar rhoncus risus. Donec molestie turpis ipsum, ac ullamcorper orci pharetra non. Pellentesque ut quam congue, feugiat nisl vel, sagittis ipsum. Pellentesque facilisis tempor tristique. Mauris condimentum egestas lectus a luctus. Proin eget ullamcorper ligula. Sed semper quis est ac condimentum. Vivamus sed velit dolor. Sed aliquam sollicitudin orci a pretium. Nulla quis sem vel turpis facilisis bibendum quis vel tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed feugiat vestibulum condimentum. Morbi sit amet pharetra orci. Etiam accumsan elit eu erat eleifend pulvinar. Vestibulum blandit gravida scelerisque.Proin non ex lobortis, suscipit purus tristique, blandit metus. Vivamus sit amet mi at lectus gravida luctus sed eget purus. Donec laoreet nec nulla quis sagittis. Cras ut eros efficitur, dictum felis vitae, cursus tortor. Sed varius ante non sapien malesuada, vitae tempor orci tincidunt. In lacus risus, efficitur ut erat vel, lacinia vulputate velit. Sed orci ligula, venenatis sed nisi id, varius scelerisque diam. In ut volutpat ligula, nec sodales sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In fermentum ac neque non suscipit. Cras aliquam, eros sed molestie lacinia, dolor dui suscipit purus, ac maximus quam leo a magna. Mauris sed ipsum a magna hendrerit interdum at non erat. Sed blandit elementum libero quis placerat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur semper auctor augue vel laoreet. Aliquam ac interdum dui, ullamcorper malesuada justo. Proin non efficitur lectus. Nam quam arcu, laoreet in volutpat non, condimentum vulputate nulla. Phasellus sit amet tellus facilisis odio dignissim maximus. Proin accumsan volutpat nunc, id pulvinar mi consequat ut. Pellentesque nec congue libero. Cras mauris nisl, pharetra sit amet semper ut, sodales quis urna. Aenean mollis quam felis, id cursus nunc pulvinar sed. Sed a urna pharetra, hendrerit massa ac, sodales urna. Pellentesque nec congue mi, in condimentum mi. Aliquam lacinia lacus at venenatis ultricies.",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here's what the ejs file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rig Guides</title>
  <%- include ('partials/product_head') %>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ========= NAV BAR ============= -->
  <%- include ('partials/navbar') %>
  <div id="build-title" class=" py-5">
    <h6 class="text-center dark-blue text-uppercase">Rig Guide</h6>
    <h3 class="text-center bold-font"><%= post.title %></h3>
    <h5 class="text-center">By <%= post.author %></h5>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid guide-container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-8 col-md-8">
        <p class="guide-content my-5 py-2"><%= post.content %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <%- include ('partials/footer') %>
  <script src="js/guide.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's the output on my deployed website at rodrigger.com
[image of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJJNp.png)

As you can see, the title and content values are templated onto the page, but the value for the property "author" is not templated b/c it should say "By [Author]"

Comment: To verify what's in the object and each of its properties, do this: `<%= JSON.stringify(post) %>` somewhere in the page

Comment: @Benny all of the properties are shown by doing that, including the author property that isn't correctly being displayed.

Comment: Next change the html markup to be minimal - leave only `<%= post.author %>` and remove all else

Comment: @Benny all I get is a blank page. <%= post.author %> is not rendering anything.

Comment: Ok, let's move to the next step: change the property name from `author` to e.g. `theAuthor`. I'm trying to do the most simple actions, as this is very strange. There must be something minor that we're missing

Comment: @Benny Page is blank still so it seems to not be templated.

Comment: Bizarre. Can you upload it to a playground such as CodePen, JSBin, etc. ao I can look at it myself?

Comment: @Benny The data is being rendered from the server so I cannot use a playground to show the code. Also, I think the issue has to do with EJS and the DB b/c I have no issues when I run my website on localhost.

Comment: But you said `<%= JSON.stringify(post) %>` shows all properties, including `author` when you run it on both the real server and localhost

Comment: @Benny Correct, so wouldn't that mean that the error has something to do with EJS?

Comment: By rule of elimination I would say yes. Wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: @Benny I was able to solve the issue. I took the DB call that retrieved the data for the post object and did JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); Therefore, there had to be something wrong with the data retrieved from my DB and not ejs.

Comment: That's nice. Curious to know what data broke it. The string "hello" seems very innocent to me.

Comment: @Benny if you look at my solution I just posted, I'm pretty sure it had to do with .find() in mongoose returning mongoose documents and not a plain javascript object. Also, thanks for taking the time out of your day to help me.

Comment: Glad it works now. Still perplexed b/c other properties showed. Perhaps there are invisible characters from the DB that are tossed away using `JSON` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue had to do with the DB and the data being retrieved from it.

I used this call to get the data from the DB:

```
 var data = await Guide.find({
    title: req.params.title
  }).exec();
```

I added this line just in case there was some "defect" in the data if that's what you'd call it.

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)):
```

and sure enough, EJS was able to correctly template the data. 
Then I realized .find() in mongoose returns the actual Mongoose Document and not a Javascript Object which is probably why EJS couldn't template the data. So I then used .lean() and it solved my issue.

```
var data = await Guide.find({
    title: req.params.title
  }).lean().exec();
```

Comment: @clota974 I have to wait two days to mark my own answer as the solution.